# Oracle forms - values not populated for undisplayed items in a data block

Tags: sql, forms, oracle, oracleforms

I have a simple data block which is based from 1 single database table.

Example:

Table T has 5 columns A,B,C,D and E.

I use two text fields in Control block(non-database data block) in which the user keys in the values for A and B and click on search button.

Based on A,B in the text boxes, I query from the table T and get A,B,C,D,E and store them in my data block while displayed only C,D and E. [Note here the query retrieves A,B,C,D and E although only C,D and E get displayed]

Below are what I did:

1) Using the data block wizard, imported all columns(A,B,C,D,E) from the table to the data block.

2) Using the Layout wizard, imported all but two columns(A,B) to be displayed on the canvas.

When I insert a record into the data block and do a COMMIT_FORM, the two columns that was left undisplayed([2] above) has a value of NULL populated for it.

My question is why does this happen and what should I do to have A and B also populated in the table when I do an insert?

Comment: What values would you _expect_ A and B to have? You can create a `pre-insert` trigger to populate them yourself.

Comment: @GriffeyDoy: This is correct and exactly what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the values of A and B should be the one of the two textfields then you should set the inital value of A and B to the corresponding items. If you query 3 records and go add a 4th the inital value will fire and the will get the value required.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried this but this sounds more like a hack. GriffeyDog's solution in the comment worked for me.